# How make my 'React Loading Spinner' component appears in the middle of my view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux

I am using the Loading as parent component of my Layoult component, but it always appears in the middle of the page, not my view. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

In the loading element, have a div which is

```
position: absolute;
height: 100vh; 
width: 100vw; 
display: flex;  
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Then have the loading animation or what you using in a child to that div. That should now be centered on your view and not the page.

Answer (score 1):

To make the custom loader component appear in the center of your view, you can achieve this by enclosing the loader gif/svg within a `div` and setting its `width` to `100%`. By doing so, the `div` will **span the entire width of its parent** or the desired container where the loader should be displayed. The remaining step is to ensure that the loader gif/svg is centered.

This can be accomplished in a straightforward manner. You have two options: you can utilize `flexbox` or apply the CSS property `text-align: center;` to the div (the parent of the loader).

Here is the code for the same:

**SearchLoader.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import "./SearchLoader.css";

const SearchLoader = () => {
    return (
        <div className='search-loader'><img src='./loaders/searching.gif' alt='searching' /></div>
    )
}

export default SearchLoader;
```

**SearchLoader.css**

```css
.search-loader {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.search-loader>img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px; // Your desired size for the loader
}
```

Hope this solves your concern.